# How to punctuate a sentence with the embedded question

Tags: punctuation

The question- how to wash children's clothes?- becomes a huge problem for young mothers.

Comment: Dashes, commas or brackets would be fine. The interrogative clause "how to wash children's clothes" is a supplement, a semantically non-restrictive interpolation here which has the NP "the question" as its semantic anchor.

Comment: Why not "The question **of** how to wash children's clothes becomes a huge problem for young mothers." ?

Comment: Your dashes are fine (use the em-dash if you are able to) and so are quote marks, for example. The question 'How to wash children's clothes ?' becomes a huge problem.

Comment: Please be very careful about the enormous difference between “the question of how to wash children’s clothes” and anything which might become a problem for young mothers. They are quite different.